# I am not able to install any new software on my ubuntu 10.10

Tags: java

There was some mistake when i was trying to install sun java on my Ubuntu 10.10

Now when I try to install any new software it shows the following Dialogue Box.
Please if you know how to solve this problem, Help me.

Dialogue Box:

**An unhandlable error occured**

There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks. Please report this error at http://launchpad.net/aptdaemon/+filebug and retry.

Details:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 768, in simulate
    return self._simulate_helper(trans, status_path)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 936, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, status, self._cache.required_download, \

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 218, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate file for the sun-java6-jre package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.

Also another Dialogue Box comes that tells me to repair package catalog.
But when I click repair, Nothing happens and that Dialogue Box comes again in few seconds.

Comment: this is not a programming question

Comment: what does "some mistake" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your package manager can't find the package.

First of all run `sudo apt-get update` from a console and look what it's telling you.

After that try installing the package again, if it still fails to find the Sun JRE try the package `openjdk-jre` or `openjdk-jre-headless`.